# Printing a square of zeros based off of squared integers--different from asterisks c++

Tags: c++

So I'm a beginner..obvi. And for my assignment I need to be able to take any integer input (ex. 3) and "Square it" and then print zeros in a square like :

```
000
000
000
```

or if the input were 2, then:

```
00
00
```

Basically I have no idea what I'm doing, but it seems like so far I have the row situation figured out. Now I can't figure out how to do the column part.

Help please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int any_number;
    string number_zeros = "0";
    string number_columns;
    //cout << "input an integer" << endl;
    cin >> any_number;
    number_columns = any_number;


        for (int i = 0; i < any_number; i++)
        {
            cout << number_zeros;

            if (i == any_number)
            {
                cout << endl;

            }

        }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You can wrap one for loop inside of another.

Comment: inside the loop, the value of `i` is never equal to `any_number` because thats the break condition. Anyhow you dont need the `if` you you put the `cout << endl;` after the loop